# Arduino not entering for loop

Tags: arduino

I'm having a problem with an if ladder and the for loops in each of them in this gameProcess function. Essentially the for loop in the (mode == 1) loop is not entered at all and I'm not sure why.

I think it's something to do with the positioning because if (mode == 1) is switched with (mode == 0), the (mode == 1) for loop will be entered but the (mode == 0) won't. Been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to spot what's up with the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
// 5 means 10 switches as one iteration is a change between one mode to another, not on and off.
int gameProcess(int mode) {
    Serial.println("> Starting game process.");
    // 4 second delay between 
    int interval = 1000;
    int initialDelay = 5000;
    enter code here:
    //delay(initialDelay);
    if (mode == 1) {
        // for a standard 25 round with a 2 sec interval
        Serial.println("starting mode 1");
        for (int i; i < 51; i++) {
            Serial.println("In loop");
            Serial.println(interval);
            flickPin(13);
            workingDelay(interval);
        }
        Serial.println("finished mode 1");
    } else if (mode == 2) {
        while(true) {
            flickPin(13);

            int minRandVal = 1000;
            int maxRandVal = 15000;

            int randomDelay = random(minRandVal, maxRandVal);
            Serial.println(randomDelay);
            workingDelay(randomDelay);
        }
    } else if (mode == 0) {
        // for 10 rounds. Find out why it needs 35 and not 20.
        Serial.println("  - Mode 0 .");
        for (int i; i < 35; i++) {
            Serial.println(interval);
            flickPin(13);
            workingDelay(interval);
        }
        Serial.println("  - finished Mode 0 .");
    } else {
        char error[80];
        sprintf(error, "Unknown mode = %d", mode);
        Serial.println(error);
    }
}
```

Here is the main loop and the initializeGame function where the gameProcess function is called from.

```
   int initializeGame(bool started, int mode) {
    if (started == true) {
        Serial.println(" -> in startMonitor, start button pressed");
        Serial.println(mode);
        gameProcess(mode);

        // if the mode is 0 (none of the lights are on), that means it's in random mode and any interval between 5 and 60 secs come up until you stop it!
        // set it back to false and turn the game light off because the game is over.
        started = false;
        digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    } else {
        started = false;
    }

    return started;
    }


    void loop()
    {
        // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
        mode = stateMonitor(activeButton);

        // now set the game mode led.
        lightUpModeLed(ledPins[mode]);

        // now check to see if the game has been initialized.
        started = startMonitor(startButton, ledPins[4], started);

        // read the state of the pushbutton value:

        // initialize game if it hasn't already started.
        // TODO this is where the loop will likely spend the majority of it's time so how can this be
        started = initializeGame(started, mode);

        saveData();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function, for example it's relation to setup() or loop() ?  Also, why not print out the mode just before the first if statement (temporarily, as an aid to debugging).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've edited the question to include the main loop. I'll echo the mode out now and take a look at what it throws.

Comment: But where are you calling the gameProcess() code that doesn't behave as expected ?

Comment: I think your problem may be that `mode = stateMonitor(activeButton);
` is not giving the values you're expecting it to return. Add printouts to watch mode's values as they change. Also, I'm not perfectly understanding your problem and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's being called from initializeGame. I've edited the post to include it, thanks again. Zmo, I checked what stateMonitor was returning and it's always returning the correct mode, it's pretty odd because the 'mode' variable is always 1 but it doesn't want to enter that for loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then install Atmel Studio and the Visual Micro Plugin then you can debug and watch what the code is doing and the values of variables.

This will take away the mystery, which it did for me.